# How to print a string from SketchUp Ruby into HTML

Tags: html, ruby, string, variables

Good afternoon,

I have a piece of code here which you can run in SketchUp's Ruby console. When you do, you will get a popup which prints the letter 'a'. However in my code, you can see I have identified 'a' as a string '50.12'.

```
        dialog = UI::HtmlDialog.new(
    {
      :dialog_title => "Observation Information Plugin",
      :scrollable => true,
      :resizable => true,
      :width => 500,
      :height => 200,
      :left => 200,
      :top => 200,
      :min_width => 50,
      :min_height => 50,
      :max_width =>1000,
      :max_height => 500,
      :style => UI::HtmlDialog::STYLE_DIALOG
    })

a = 50.12
a = a.to_s

html = "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type = 'text/javascript'>
            document.write('<p>a</p>');
        </script>
    </body>
</html> 
"

dialog.set_html(html)
dialog.show
```

What can I do to modify the HTML portion of my code to get the script to print 50.12 to the screen instead of the letter 'a'?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should add a sketchup tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use string interpolation.  Replace `document.write('<p>a</p>');` with `document.write('<p>#{a}</p>');`